# How to render templates with jinja2 using json in python?

Tags: python, json, jinja2

I'm trying to directly load json data to render templates using jinja2 and I'm having trouble doing so without hardcoding values. For example,

```
msg = template.render(posts=config[0]['context']['posts'])
```

Here, I've hardcoded the variable "posts" which exists in my json file and "config" is simply a python dict that I've loaded the json data into. Here's a snippet of the json file:

```
[
  {
    "url": "/",
    "template": "index.html",
    "context": {
      "logname": "gjgk",
      "posts": [
        {
          "postid": "3",
          "owner": "ggkghj",
          "likes": 1,
          "comments": [
            {
              "owner": "dsf",
              "text": "#sadf"
            }
          ]
        }
]
```

If "posts" was named something else, how would I reflect this in my python code? Should I change the variable names written in my template file?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add template to the post.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution. I used kwargs:

```
for x in config[0]['context']:
        msg = template.render(**{x:config[0]['context'][x]})
```